# hive cannot display special characters

Tags: hive, character-encoding, hbase

I created a hive table on a hbase table
like that

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE RGPD.TEST_TAB(
`HBASE_ID` STRING,
`INTEGRATION_ID` STRING,
`LAST_NAME` STRING,
`MAIDEN_NAME` STRING,
`FST_NAME` STRING,
`PER_TITLE` STRING,
`BIRTH_DT` STRING
)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('hbase.columns.mapping'=':key,all:integration_id,all:last_name,all:maiden_name,all:fst_name,all:per_title,all:birth_dt','serialization.encoding'='UTF-8')
TBLPROPERTIES ('hbase.table.name'='key:TEST_TAB');
```

when I make a select query in hive
I have a return like this:

```
10131472        FRAN�OIS
```

while the query in hbase returns:

```
01061948        FRAN\xC7OIS
```

I know this is a charset (utf-8) issue but I have not found the solution
Any help please !!

Comment: I don't know Hive, but, it looks to me as if it is returning valid utf-8 but you are trying to **display** the result in a different encoding (possibly an ASCII or ANSI type) wherethe byte C7 does not have a meaning.

Comment: no I do not think so because I use the same display for **hbase** and **hive**.I created another hive table "TEST_TAB_TXT" and I made an insert into. in the text file I had a weird character

Comment: Was it a wierd display of the character, or an actual replacement? You'll need to dump the content with a hex-editor or similar.

Comment: I think the orginal text is `FRANÇOIS` as `C7` represents `Ç` The question is how are you inserting data.

Comment: I have a SQLsever database, 
I made the import to the HADOOP cluster in the HBase table **hbase.table.name**. After I created an external hive table on this table.the data is readable in hbase but not in hive.